# Solution in Slick to Map a Future[Option] DB result to a value

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm doing this in `play` framework to get the relation between a command and a execution table using `slick`.

```
class ExecutionsTable(tag: Tag) extends BaseTable[Execution](tag, "executions") {
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def execution = column[String]("execution")
    def commandId = column[Long]("command_id")
    def * = (id, name, execution, commandId) <> (Execution.tupled, Execution.unapply)
    def command = foreignKey("commands", commandId, commandsTableQ)(_.id)

    implicit val CommandToLong = MappedColumnType.base[Long, Command] (
      id => {
        val cmd = Await.result(new CommandsDAO().findById(id), 1 second)
        cmd.get
      },
      cmd => cmd.id
    )
```

`findById` returns a `Future[Option[Command]]` I'm trying to use this method which I'm not sure is the best solution for this.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Hmm.  I don't have a good answer, but this looks pretty dangerous to me.  As a general rule, `Await` should be considered poison inside of Play -- it breaks the threading design, and should only used if you know what you're doing.  (And that `.get` risks mysterious crashes.)  Do you really need the custom `Command` type? I sympathize with the desire for it (and I assume you're using it here for the foreign key relation?), but this code looks likely to cause subtle problems in production...

Comment: I was advised in Slick gitter channel to not do this implementation since it is dependent on a Future result and for the MappedColumnType it has no good solution. I was recommended to do a full SQL Query

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to handle errors? If you do, I suggest you use a flatMap and then pattern match again to see if you function actually returns something. Here you go, Something along these lines :

```
val x : Future[Option[String]] = Future(Option("1"))

val id = x.flatMap(optId => optId match {
  case Some(id) => id
  case None => throw new Exception("No ID.")
}
```

Comment: "Cannot resolve flatMap with such signature" Expected Option[Command] => Future[NotInferedS] , actual: Option[Command] => Any

Comment: You should use a map, not a flatMap.

Comment: But I need to return the Command object in his example case the "1"

Comment: You can do this :

  val id = x.map {
    case Some(x) => x
  }

This way you ignore any cases that are None by the way.
Which is basically what @C4stor said. Cheers.

Comment: Doing that I get: found : scala.concurrent.Future[models.entities.Command] required: models.entities.Command , Can't get command out of the future

Comment: i see, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Here, you can use this.. I guess since future is being used synchronously in this sense, you can await.. but you can refactor a little bit on your get and use this. This is something I'm currently using in one of my projects wiht slick  and it works fine.  :
val x : Future[Option[String]] = Future(Option("1"))

  val id = Await.result(x, 10 seconds).getOrElse(throw new Exception("Id doesn't exist"))
  println(id)